# What's the difference between "helpful" and "Helpful" flags?

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags

Looks like a text inconsistency to me:

- Spam flags are *Helpful*
- Other flags are *helpful*

---

> [image]

Comment: Appears to only happen on Spam flags, that it capitalizes. Happens to me also

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Absolutely nothing, except that the renderer for *moderator messages* included a `ToLower()`, and the renderer for *votes* (i.e. spam or offensive) did not. Rectified in the next build.